# Difference between async and async="true"

Tags: asynchronous, syntax, attributes, blogger, adsense

While adding adsense async ad code (which has async attribute) in Blogger HTML editor, I'm shown an error message that the attribute async must be followed by an =. Adsense ad code uses

Now is there any difference between using just async and async="true" ?

Answer (score 0):

you can convert the whole adsense ad code into HTML entity encoder and then place in anywhere in blogger HTML... here's the link where you can do this easily..
http://starsblogging.blogspot.com/2013/02/online-html-entity-encoder.html

Answer (score 0):

Nothing.. both are basically same

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).